# Check if image points intersects with a circle

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, intersection

I am trying to detect shoulders.
In the colored picture you can see 2 circles, the big circle intersects with the edge picture in 4 points.
I made the edge thiner and put all the edge points(x,y) in an array.
Now i'm trying to find the intersection points using the circle equation: (x1 - x) + (y1 -y) - r^2 = 0.
The problem, the equation is zero only once(sometimes never). I rounded the center points and radius of circle so I can get a specific pixel... didn't help !

color pic :
[image]

edge pic : 
[image]

code:

get circle:

```
%% im - colored image.
%  x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 - are the right eye left eye and chin points.
%  The function calculates a new circule and sends its center points and 
%  radius back.



function [cx,cy,newRadius] = calcFaceCircle(im,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) 


m1 = (y1 - y3)/(x1-x3);
m2 = (y2 - y3)/(x2-x3);

d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2);

centerX = ((m1*m2*(y2-y1) + m2*(x2 + x3) - m1*(x1 + x3))/(2*(m2-m1)));
centerY = (-(1/m1)*(centerX - (x3 + x2)/2) + (y3 + y2)/2);

radius = (sqrt((x1 - centerX)^2 + (y1 - centerY)^2));
%% new circle radius
newRadius = round(radius * 1.65);


newCircleX = (x1+x2)/2; 
newCircleY = (y1+y2)/2;
%% new circle center points
cx = round(newCircleX + sqrt(newRadius^2-(d/2)^2)*(y1-y2)/d);
cy = round(newCircleY + sqrt(newRadius^2-(d/2)^2)*(x2-x1)/d);

%% display the image with circles and points
figure(01);
imshow(im);
hold on; 

ang=0:0.01:2*pi; 
xp=radius*cos(ang);
yp=radius*sin(ang);
plot(x1,y1,'.');
plot(x2,y2,'.');
plot(x3,y3,'.');

plot(centerX+xp,centerY+yp);

xp=newRadius*cos(ang);
yp=newRadius*sin(ang);
plot(cx+xp,cy+yp);

hold off;

end
```

get shoulders :

```
%% 
%edgeFun - array of edge image points (x,y).
%  x - circle's center X.
%  y - circle's center Y.
%  r - circle's radios
%
% The function calculates the interection points between edgeFunc and the
% circle.
% The funciton returns the first intersection and last intersection.

function [xL,xR] = getCropInfo(edgeFunc,x,y,r)

j=1;
flag = 0;
xL = -1;
xR = -1;
count = 0;

if(x > 0 && y > 0 && r > 0)


    X = edgeFunc(:,2);     

    [edgeX,edgeY] = size(X);


    for i = 1:edgeX
        x1 = edgeFunc(i,2);
        y1 = edgeFunc(i,1); 

        % check if the points intersect with the circle
        if((floor((x-x1)^2 + (-y+y1)^2 - r^2) == 0))
            if(flag == 0)  % check if first intersection point found
                disp('found');
                flag = 1;
                xL = i;  % first point
            end

            j = i;  % last point
            count = count + 1;
        end

        xR = j;

    end


else

    return;

end
if(count == 4)
    disp('ok');

end
```

Comment: so basically, you have the edge of the img, and a circle on the same coordinate system and you want to find all the intersects?

Comment: Correct !  I have a feeling the equation will never return zero... It's not a code issue

Comment: it is possible to never return zero due to resolution in your coordinate system. There are ways around it by matlab plot and estimating the intersect manually (why would I even suggest this?) or you could look at polyxpoly, where you turn your edge into a polyline - http://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html

Comment: ok, so polyxpoly(x1,y1,x2,y2) as x1,y1 are the circle coordinates ? how do I get that ? on the link : [latc, lonc] = scircle1(lat0, lon0, km2deg(rad)); , but km2deg takes radios in KM but my radios is in pixels.

Comment: your circle needs to be a polyline as well, if you look at the first example, you need to basically give the full coordinates of your circle in the format of x and y.

Comment: The test on the floor of F(x,y) returns true when 0<=F(x, y)<1. Are you sure this is the right way ? Safer would be to take the curve vertices two by two and check for a change of sign of F(x, y).

Comment: Yes after all I checked when the sign changes and took those pixels as the intersection points

Answer (score 1):

to make your life easier, I gave the code a try:

```
x1 = [-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]; %//My edge, which is no where as handsome as yours
y1 = [-5,3,6,5,5,6,3,-5];

ang = 1:0.1:2*pi;
xp=4*cos(ang);  %//My circle, which is no where as good looking as yours
yp=4*sin(ang);

[xi,yi] = polyxpoly(x1,y1,xp,yp);  //Evaluate the intersects by interpolation

figure 
plot(x1,y1,'r')
hold on
plot(xp,yp,'b')

mapshow(xi,yi,'DisplayType','point','Marker','o');
```

> > xi =
> >         1.8113;
> >        -3.0529;
> >        -3.5942;
> >         2.7387
> >
> > yi =     3.5662;
> >         2.5771;
> >        -1.7535;
> >        -2.9094

[image: To add insults to my simulation]

As you can see, it doesn't matter how low res the data is, it will always interpolate and evaluate the point of intersection, which is ideally what you want (cause you might want to change the resolution of your image). polyxpoly uses the standard coordinate system, so it is very easy to adapt for a image pixel coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

It would better to register edge segments where edge crosses the circle. For the initial and ending points of such segment value of

S =  (x1 - x) + (y1 -y) - r^2

will have different signs (zero for exact coincidence).

Comment: with the image coordinate system say 512 pixel * 512 pixels, the intersections might be missed (even if the lines actually intersected).

Comment: Not much help to the OP, but there are several very good mapping packages for `R` which will do this sort of thing straight-off.